# Progress Bar elements Alignment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out why the first step of the progress bar is aligned slighty up vs the other steps. Its only a couple pixels but I can't figure out why it's not aligning properly. You will see the circle with the #1 inside vertically centered higher than the others... which I can't seem to fix because it's only happening on my end!

[Problem image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xwik.png)

[image: Problem image with line here]

CSS/HTML

```css
.progressbar {
      counter-reset: step;
  }
  .progressbar li {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 25%;
      float: left;
      font-size: 12px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #7d7d7d;
  }
  .progressbar li:before {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      content: counter(step);
      counter-increment: step;
      line-height: 30px;
      border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
  }
  .progressbar li:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
      top: 15px;
      left: -50%;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .progressbar li:first-child:after {
      content: none;
  }
  .progressbar li.active {
      color: green;
  }
  .progressbar li.active:before {
      border-color: #55b776;
  }
  .progressbar li.active + li:after {
      background-color: #55b776;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Complete Basic Information</li>
    <li>Add Secondary Owner(s)</li>
    <li>Review</li>
    <li>Export</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your current code works as desired in the snippet. In order for anyone to work on this with you, we need to be able to reproduce the issue you are experiencing, which does not appear to be possible using the code you have provided.

Comment: Can you specify what browser and version you are using when you are having the issue?

Comment: It's possible that other styles are affecting the result. you may need to use the browsers dev tools to see what CSS rules are affecting the misplaced elements. for chrome see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/ and for firefox see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

Comment: @AryeEidelman I am using chrome latest version. I have found the same issue where it is working everywhere else but just not in my bootstrap template. I even renamed the container css class that the html code is in... the first step is still slightly off centered. Is there another way for me to ensure the html script isn't being interfered with anything else? I can't figure this out! Any additional help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You can use the [dev tools inspect element tool](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/#view) and look at the Styles panel on the first li, also look at the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements and the progressbar. If that doesn't help take screenshots of the styles panel (for each of those four elements) and add them to your question so we can have a look. (You can embed the images directly instead of linking elsewhere.)